# Is there any way to view history of time-zone settings in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, timezone

One of our servers has been set with an incorrect time zone for months and it has affected some of our data in SQL Server. Is there any way to see when time zone settings were made on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the time on my workstation and it wrote an event to the windows system event log with an eventId of 1.  Text of log below:

```
The system time has changed to ‎2011‎-‎08‎-‎18T18:49:24.356138400Z from ‎2011‎-‎08‎-‎18T18:49:24.356138400Z.
```

Answer (score 1):

if you check the system logs it will show when the time change was done.